# Geocode not appearing

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Below is the javascript for my Geocode. My map will not appear, and I cannot seem to find my error. Please advise.

I'm trying to show the "true" value of the actual location. API was generated appropriately on Google's developers website.

```
<script>
var geocoder;
var map;
  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.Latlng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      Center: latlng
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
  }

  function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.get.getElementById('address').value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else {

        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
    });
  }

</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=drawing&sensor=true"></script>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code/HTML to reproduce the problem (or a jsfiddle or a link to a map that exhibits the issue).

Comment: Fix your javascript errors.

Answer (score 2):

You have at least 3 javascript errors which will cause issues:

1. javascript is case sensitive:

   - Center is not the same as center
   - Latlng is not the same as LatLng
2. there is a missing comma after "Center: latlng" in the mapOptions
3. this is incorrect (extra ".get"):

   var address = document.get.getElementById('address').value;

should be:

```
var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
```

And as `Jimmie Johansson` observed, there is no call to initialize (or for that matter codeAddress)

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_Geocoder.html)

Answer (score 1):

Do you run initialize() anywhere? Without that your map won't show up.